# WebKit or Gecko with .NET

Tags: .net, webkit, gecko

In my searching I've found [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/), but I'm not sure that's what I'm aiming for. To be clear, I'm aiming to use a rendering engine like Gecko or Webkit with .NET. I'm hoping to use it within a service or website back-end to allow the rendering engine complete the rendering of the webpage and let JavaScript do its thing, and then return the end result of the DOM to the caller. Are there any other .NET implementations?

Comment: How would that be useful?  If you want to use Javascript to render a page on the server there are better ways to go about it.  Many of the Gecko/Webkit hacks that I've seen require creating a desktop window, which is not a practical solution on a server.

Answer (score 3):

IF you want a "windowless" rendering engine then try http://awesomium.com/ .

It is based on Chrome/WebKit and supports among other things the scenario you describe.

There is a free license, a "Pro" license and a source code license...